# NSXMLParser refresh leak

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, rss, refresh, nsxmlparser

I have strange problem with my app.
When I open my app it parses an RSS feed and displays the results in a tableview and there are no leaks BUT if I press my refresh button it leaks (a lot) :(

My Project: [Link](http://www.mediafire.com/?0ogg4k5te61o822)

Code:
viewDidLoad

```
UIBarButtonItem *ShareButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(tableView_ReFresh)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = ShareButton;
[ShareButton release];
```

viewDidAppear

```
if ([stories count] == 0) {
    NSURL *path = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://feeds.feedburner.com/TheAppleBlog"];
    [self parseXMLFileAtURL:path];
    [path release];
}
```

tableView_ReFresh

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
NSURL *path = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://feeds.feedburner.com/TheAppleBlog"];
[self parseXMLFileAtURL:path];
[self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
[path release];
[pool drain];
```

reloadData

```
[blogTable reloadData];
```

parseXMLFileAtURL

```
stories = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:0];
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setDiskCapacity:0];
NSData *xml = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];   
rssParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xml];
[rssParser setDelegate:self];
// Depending on the XML document you're parsing, you may want to enable these features of NSXMLParser.
[rssParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
[rssParser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
[rssParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
[rssParser setDelegate:self];
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
[rssParser parse];
[xml release];
```

didStartElement

```
currentElement = [[elementName copy]autorelease];
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
    // clear out our story item caches...
    item = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]autorelease];
    currentTitle = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    currentDate = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    currentContent = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    currentPostID = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    currentCommentLink = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    currentCommentNum = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
}
```

didEndElement

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
    // save values to an item, then store that item into the array...
    [item setObject:currentTitle forKey:@"title"];
    [item setObject:currentPostID forKey:@"link"];
    [item setObject:currentContent forKey:@"Content"];
    [item setObject:currentDate forKey:@"date"];
    [item setObject:currentCommentLink forKey:@"commentRssLink"];
    [item setObject:currentCommentNum forKey:@"commentsNum"];

    [stories addObject:[item copy]];
    NSLog(@"adding story: %@", currentPostID);
    //NSLog(@"adding story: %@", currentContent);
}
```

foundCharacters

```
if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
    [currentTitle appendString:string];
} else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"guid"]) {
    [currentPostID appendString:string];
} else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"content:encoded"]) {       
    [currentContent appendString:string];
} else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"pubDate"]) {
    [currentDate appendString:string];
} else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"wfw:commentRss"]) {
    [currentCommentLink appendString:string];
} else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"slash:comments"]) {
    [currentCommentNum appendString:string];
}
```

parserDidEndDocument

```
[blogTable reloadData];
```

dealloc

```
[super dealloc];
[currentElement release];
[rssParser release];
[stories release];
[item release];
[currentTitle release];
[currentDate release];
[currentContent release];
[currentPostID release];
[currentCommentLink release];
[currentCommentNum release];
```

How do I fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read the documentation about memory management. First of each time you parse you are allocating the NSXMLParser again and then for each "item" element in the XML file you're allocating your strings again without releasing them.

The easiest route, without fully understanding the problem, is to create properties for your ivars and call 'self.ivar =' when you want to assign a new value to them. The generated setters will take care of releasing the memory that the variable was previously pointing to.

I strongly recommend that you read this though:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html

Answer (score 0):

My guess this is your leak:

```
stories = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

You're releasing `stories` in your dealloc, which I assume is a property, which I assume you have declared with `retain`. If I am correct, you should be able to fix this by either doing (A) `self.stores = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];` or (B) by putting `[stories release];` before that line.

Assuming your version of Xcode is reasonably up-to-date, if you run your code with Build & Analyze I would guess it would catch this issue.

Comment: @user535351 sorry, I don't have time to look at your project. Meanwhile, have you read the advice I gave you (run Build & Analyze to see what it says)? Have you read the Apple documentation on memory management?